# Qual é o valor máximo e mínimo para z-index?

Tags: css

Estava eu discutindo com alguns amigos sobre colocar `99999` no `z-index` para garantir que o elemento tenho o mais alto grau de prioridade de sobreposição sobre outro elemento.

Mas ao pensar sobre isso, me veio uma pequena curiosidade:

- Qual é o valor máximo para `z-index`?
- Qual é o valor mínimo para `z-index`, visto que o mesmo suporta valores negativos?

Answer (score 6):

Informações retiradas da internet:

```
│ Browser              │ Max z─index value │ When exceeded, value changes to: │
╞══════════════════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════╡
│ Firefox 0 - 2        │ 2147483647        │ element disappears               │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firefox 3            │ 2147483647        │ 0                                │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firefox 4+           │ 2147483647        │ 2147483647                       │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│ Safari 0 - 3         │ 16777271          │ 16777271                         │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│ Safari 4+            │ 2147483647        │ 2147483647                       │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│ Internet Explorer 6+ │ 2147483647        │ 2147483647                       │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│ Chrome 29+           │ 2147483647        │ 2147483647                       │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│ Opera 9+             │ 2147483647        │ 2147483647                       │
```

Leia mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/minimum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index).

Comment: Informações estão atualizadas para as versões atuais dos navegadores?

Answer (score 4):

[Se você navegar na ultima versão da especificação](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/) e for na [lista de propriedades](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#properties) e chegar na propriedade z-index, [lá tem a ultima definição da mesma](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#propdef-z-index):

> - **Name**: z-index
> - **Value**:  auto | **< integer >**
> - **Initial**:    auto
> - **Applies to**: positioned elements
> - **Inherited**:  no
> - **Percentages**:    N/A
> - **Computed value**: the keyword auto or an integer
> - **Canonical order**:    per grammar
> - **Animatable**: < integer >
> - **Animation type**: by computed value

O **value** é do tipo **integer**, que é o mesmo que dizer 2³² (-2147483648 até +2147483647).

Agora se os browsers vão seguir esse valor a risca, seria uma outra tarefa a ser descoberta.

[Nesta outra resposta na stackouverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/minimum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index) em inglês, tem respostas mais elaboradas.