# Como organizar a utilização do atributo z-index?

Tags: javascript, css

Uma coisa que sempre tive impressão no CSS de ser a coisa mais desorganizada é o uso do `z-index`.

Muitas vezes alguns frameworks/bibliotecas, ou até mesmo alguns desenvolvedores, colocam um valor exagerado no `z-index`, causando problemas com organização dos mesmos.

Eu sempre me perguntei, por exemplo, se existia uma maneira de pegar o `z-index` máximo usado em todo o documento (imagino que, se for possível, somente pelo Javascript). Por exemplo, se o elemento `a` usa `z-index` 2 e o `b` usa `3`, haveria alguma forma de capturar o `3` e o respectivo elemento?

Outra coisa: Existe alguma alternativa, padrão ou organização para evitar a confusão em relação ao uso do  `z-index`? Atualmente, eu praticamente tenho que lembrar onde, em cada parte do projeto, defini os atributos `z-index` e ir incrementando "mentalmente".

Existe alguma maneira mais fácil de organizar a  utilização de um `z-index` num projeto grande, para evitar transtornos com sobreposição? Existe algum outro atributo?

**Observação**: Eu lembro até de já ter perguntando algo [parecido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/311511/qual-%c3%a9-o-valor-m%c3%a1ximo-e-m%c3%adnimo-para-z-index), mas dessa vez a dúvida é outra.

Comment: z-index pode ser relativo ao elemento. Um z-index 999 pode ficar atrás de um z-index -1 de um elemento que já esteja por cima do parent do 999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara não vou dar uma resposta super aprofundada, mas vou apenas abordar diretamente.

Vc pode ter um `stack` de `z-index` para cada elemento sequencia `pai>filho>neto`. Se o Pai tiver `position:relative`, os filhos e netos, vão ter o `z-index` "indexado" ao pai. Como o @bacco comentou, vc pode ter sim um elemento com `z-index:999` abaixo de um `z-index: -1;`

Veja o exemplo

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.25);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
.box:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.25);
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}
.filho {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  z-index: 999;
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="filho">
    z-index: -1
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Uma forma de manter as coisas sob-controle**

Vc pode criar `utilities` de `z-index` para te ajudar. No seu projeto vc pode estabelecer um número `X` máximo de sobreposição no `eixo Z` como o Material Design faz por exemplo. https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#elevation-in-material-design

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então no seu código vc poderia ter algo como abaixo.

```
.z1 {
  z-index: 1;
}
.z2 {
  z-index: 2;
}
.z3 {
  z-index: 3;
}

<div class="box z1">
  <div class="filho z1"></div>
  <div class="filho z2"></div>
</div>
```

Dessa forma vc não coloca um z-index para cada classe no CSS, vc coloca uma classe de `z-index` para cada elemento no HTML. **Isso não é regra!** É apenas uma metodologia que pode ser interessante pra vc ou não. Ao meu ver colocando `z1`, `z2` nas classes no HTML fica mais intuitivo perceber como o `stack` do `eixo Z` está progredindo. Mas não deixa de ser uma maneira de manter o controle do `z-index`, mas sempre lembrando do `stack` relativo mostrado acima...

Uma imagem ilustrativa para perceber visualmente com o auxílio do *shadow* como o `eixo Z` pode se comportar.

[image]